# How would I make text dynamic from events?

Tags: java, dynamic

Hello well I made a code that will download an app, and that's all working fine.

My question is I want to display on the frame "Please wait until the jar is done downloading...50% done" I want the 50% to change with the % left of the file being downloaded.

I got that all set but the part where it changes is what is not working.

Heres my code:

```
        while(( length = inputstream.read(buffer)) > -1)
    {
        down += length;

        bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0 , length);
        String text = clientDL.label1.getText();
        text +=  getPerc() + "%";
    }
```

And here is my getPerc() method:

```
    private  int getPerc() {

    return  (down / (sizeOfClient + 1)) * 100;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to change (per)%done to (per)%remaining after 50% done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for

> "Please wait until the jar is done downloading...50% done" **i want
>   the 50% to change with the % left of the file being downloaded.**

```
while(( length = inputstream.read(buffer)) > -1)
               {
            down += length;
                    bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0 , length);
            String text = clientDL.label1.getText();
             int perc = getPerc();

     if(perc <= 50)        
    {
    text +=  getPerc() + "% done";
    }else
    {
     text ="Please wait until the jar is downloading..."
     text = text + (100 - perc) + " % remaining"
    } 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is that Java doesn't work on that pointer-like logic, so using a getter  to get a variable and then assigning a new value to that variable will not do anything.

What you are looking for is

```
clientDL.label1.setText("Whatever text you want to put in the label");
```

(for the record, you probably want to define a getter for that label, rather than accessing directly to label1, which is bad practice)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the carriage return symbol

`System.out.print("10%\r")`

EDIT: You're not using stdout, my bad. See silverlord's answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be more or less something like this:

```
 String text = clientDL.label1.getText();
 while(( length = inputstream.read(buffer)) > -1){
    down += length;

    bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0 , length);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
          clientDL.label1.setText(text +  getPerc() + "%");
       }
    });
}
```

(I assume you are downloading the file in a thread that is not AWT-Event-Queue)

Answer (score 0):

```
I dont have enough reputation to comment i am unable to provide you solution adding comment to your question. Anyway i tried similar scenario
I think there is a problem with your clientDL.label1.getText(); just like what solutions suggested by Silverlord. Please refer Silverlord answer


public class Checker {
int length = 0;
InputStreamReader inputstream;
FileInputStream fis = null;

    public void display() throws IOException
    {
         fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\298610\\Documents\\test.txt");
        inputstream = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        int i=0;
        while(( length = inputstream.read()) > -1)
            {
               if(i<getPerc().length)
               {
                String text = null;
                text = getPerc()[i] + "%";
                System.out.println("Hi man "+text);
               }
                i++;
            }
    }

     private  int[] getPerc() {

            return  new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
        }

     public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException
     {
         Checker w =new Checker();
         w.display();
     }
}
```

I am getting output like :
Hi man 10%
Hi man 20%
Hi man 30%
Hi man 40%
Hi man 50%
Hi man 60%
Hi man 70%
Hi man 80%
Hi man 90%
Hi man 100%